# Getting all possible consecutive 4 digit numbers from a 10 digit number

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to make a regex to get all the possible **consecutive 4 digit** numbers from a 10 digit number. Like

```
num = "2345678901";
```

**Output :**
`2345`, `3456`, `4567`, `5678`, `6789`, `7890`, `8901`

These simple regex are not working:

```
[\d]{4}
(\d\d\d\d)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `(?=(\d{4}))` regex to match overlapping matches.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3D(%5Cd%7B4%7D))&i=2345678901)

The regexes you are using are all consuming the 4 digit chunks of text, and thus the overlapping values are not matched. With `(?=...)` positive lookahead, you can test *each* position inside the input string, and *capture* 4 digit chunks from those positions, without *consuming* the characters (i.e. without moving the regex engine pointer to the location after these 4 digit chunks).

[image]

[C# demo](http://ideone.com/KkubT7):

```
var data = "2345678901";
var res = Regex.Matches(data, @"(?=(\d{4}))")
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value)
            .ToList();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", res));
```

Comment: This doesn't actually match the desired result, but matches every combination and puts it into a capture group for that match... Yes, it works and I don't think it's possible without a lookahead, but it's a worthy note I think.

Comment: @ThomasWeller: `(?=...)` is a positive lookahead, a zero-width assertion, a construct letting us check for (or enforce) presence of some character(s) *after* the current location inside the string. Bikonja: I compared my results with the expected ones, and they are the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. However, In Notepad++, it seems to be not working even I have selected the "Regular Expression" radio button.

Comment: @Koder101: Regex != Regex. There are different sorts of them. The question should not be tagged .NET and Notepad++ simultaneously, since that contradicts.

Comment: @Koder101 Look at my comment for the answer. Notepad++ does not know (in find, only in replace) about capture groups in matches, hence the working C# code, but non-working Notepad++ regex. I don't think this is possible in Notepad++.

Comment: @Koder101: In Notepad++, use `(?=(\d{4}))` and replace with `\nOVERLAPPED: $1\n`. Then, bookmark the overlapped ones with `^OVERLAPPED:\h*\d{4}$` regex, copy all the bookmarked lines to a new file and remove "OVERLAPPED: ". It is not straight-forward, but possible.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : Thanks for your effort. I appreciate. :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you absolutely need to use Regex? The same operation can be achieved much more quickly using a simple loop.

```
private IEnumerable<string> getnums(string num)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < num.Length - 3; i++)
    {
        yield return num.Substring(i, 4);
    }
}

private IEnumerable<string> DoIt(string num)
{
    var res = Regex.Matches(num, @"(?=(\d{4}))")
                .Cast<Match>()
                .Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value)
                .ToList();
    return (IEnumerable<string>)res;

}
```

On average the simple loop takes about half the time of the RegEx version.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var num = "2345678901";

    Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();

    timer.Start();
    foreach (var number in getnums(num))
    {
        // Yum yum numbers
    }
    timer.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(timer.Elapsed.Ticks);

    timer.Reset();

    timer.Start();
    foreach (var number in DoIt(num))
    {
        // Yum yum numbers
    }
    timer.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(timer.Elapsed.Ticks);
}
```

Comment: Good comparison and thanks for your approach. If I answer your question  then, Yes, it was necessary to use Regex. Because the question is just a smaller part of some task, in reality I was dealing with - 


1. 1000 digits long number.

2. The actual requirement was to get all possible 13 digit numbers, having no zeros. So my modified Regex would be - **@"(?=([1-9]{13}))"**
3. And then doing some tasks with those numbers.

The reason I chose to go with Regex is because of the flexibility it provides and the separation of concern.